# IoT LoRaWAN Tracking Node with Acsip S76G SoC

Tags: gps, lora, datasheet

I'm developing a LoRaWAN tracking node based on a TTGO T-Motion board based on Acsip S76G SoC. This SoC incoporates a STM32L073RZ controller, a Semtech SX1276 LoRa Modem and a Sony CXD5603 GNSS chip.
To optimize power consumption I played a little bit with the initialization of the Sony chip. Unfortunately I do not have a data sheet and user manual for this chip. I asked Sony semiconductor for the documents but they told me that they don't have. I can not believe that.
So is there somebody in the community, who has some documentation on the mentioned GNSS chip.
Thanks a lot for your support.

Wolfgang

I tried to get information from Sony semiconductor and from Acsip
I expect some examples for initialization of CXD5603GF GNSS chip, better a data sheet and/or user manual

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.